# Disable a column of a QTreeWidgetItem or remove set CheckBox

Tags: c++, qt, qtreewidgetitem

I have `QTreeWidgetItem` set in a `QTreeWidget` with 2 columns. Both cells got a CheckBox set by `setCheckState(...)`.

When the user unchecks the CheckBox in my first column I uncheck the second CheckBox in column 2.

Now, I would like to prevent the user to check this second CheckBox again. Is it possible to remove this CheckBox in column 2 or to disable only this cell?
So far I have just seen that all the flags work on the complete item and a set CheckBox won't disapear.

Btw. The items are not editable and I don't want to use a `QTableWidget`/`-Item`.

#### Update:

The CheckBox will be automatically inserted by Qt when I call setCheckState for the item:

```
QTreeWidgetItem *item = new QTreeWidgetItem(ui.TreeWidget);
item->setCheckState(0, Qt::Checked);
```

After the `new` the item does not own a CheckBox (by Qt default). Calling `setCheckState(...)` I automatically insert a CheckBox (here in column 0) with the `Qt::CheckState` I want.

But after I have done it there's no way to remove the CheckBox - so it seems.

Maybe anyone got a solution how I can get rid of this CheckBox at a later time? Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Can you tell how you add your two checkboxes in your QTreeWidgetItem? If you keep them in a variable, you may be able to access them (and their methods).

Answer (score 9):

This will do it:

```
item->setData(0, Qt::CheckStateRole, QVariant());           //No checkbox at all (what you wanted)
```

any of these others will show the checkbox space

```
item->setData(0, Qt::CheckStateRole, Qt::Unchecked);        //Unchecked checkbox
item->setData(0, Qt::CheckStateRole, Qt::Checked);          //Checked checkbox
item->setData(0, Qt::CheckStateRole, Qt::PartiallyChecked); //Partially checked checkbox (gray)
```

The setCheckState method can not set 'no check state', only Checked, PartiallyChecked or Unckecked.